# Missing pma_number in classification endpoint Aug2020 release

Tags: openfda

I downloaded the device classification dataset from [here](https://open.fda.gov/apis/device/classification/download/)

Despite being listed in the searchable fields in the documentation, the openFDA field "pma_number" appears to be missing (at least in the Aug2020 release).

Also, does this dataset link the medical device identified with k_number with the facility is manufactured in? It is not clear to me the information about fei_number/registration_number. As an alternative, is it possible to recover information about where the specific medical device is manufactured?

Answer (score 0):

`grep "\"pma_number\"" device-classification-0001-of-0001.json | wc -l` yields `406`, which means 406 records do have `pma_number` values.

Please note that this specific dataset relies on harmonization to determine `pma_number`, which is not always feasible and thus many records will inevitably miss `pma_number` entries.

If you have a `k_number` value, you could query the [Device Registrations & Listings Overview](https://open.fda.gov/apis/device/registrationlisting/) endpoint to determine manufacturing information, such as

https://api.fda.gov/device/registrationlisting.json?search=k_number:%22K120954%22